# Why my react component isn't updating the image gallery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

Hi I am new to react and I would like to know why my image gallery isn't updating when clicking on the date Tab. I made on purpose the fact that once you clicked on the tab, it "pops" one object of the array, but it isn't updating in real time. I can see the result only if I change the size of the window. Is there something to fix it?

**galleryPage.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import ImageGrid from '../components/image-grid/ImageGrid';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Text from '../components/text/Text';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const photos = [
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/2ShvY8Lf6l0/800x599',
    width: 4,
    height: 3,
    date: '2020',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799',
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    date: '2020',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/qDkso9nvCg0/600x799',
    width: 3,
    height: 4,
    date: '2018',
  },
  {
    src: 'https://source.unsplash.com/iecJiKe_RNg/600x799',
    width: 3,
    height: 4,
    date: '2021',
  },
];

const GalleryPage = () => {
  const marginSpaceY = 30;
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
  const [filterDate, setFilterDate] = React.useState(currentYear);
 
const handleChangeDate = (event, newDate) => {
    setFilterDate(newDate);
    console.log(newDate);

    photos.pop();
    
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
        {/* Year */}
        <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="flex-start">
          <StyledTabs
            variant="scrollable"
            value={filterDate}
            onChange={handleChangeDate}
            aria-label="styled tabs example"
          >
            <StyledTab label="2019" value="2019" />
            <StyledTab label="2020" value="2020" />
            <StyledTab label="2021" value="2021" />
          </StyledTabs>
        </Grid>
      </Box>


      <Box mb={marginSpaceY}>
        <ImageGrid photos={photos}></ImageGrid>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GalleryPage;
```

**imageGrid.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { SRLWrapper } from 'simple-react-lightbox';
import Gallery from 'react-photo-gallery';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const options = {
  settings: {
    slideTransitionSpeed: 0.1,
    disablePanzoom: true,
    showThumbnailsButton: true,
  },
  buttons: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(30,30,36,0.3)',
    showThumbnailsButton: false,
  },
};

const ImageGrid = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="flex-start">
        <Box width="90%" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
          <SRLWrapper options={options}>
            <Gallery photos={props.photos}></Gallery>
          </SRLWrapper>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageGrid;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `onChange={handleChangeDate}` be `onClick={handleChangeDate}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're always rendering all the photos in the `photos` array. You should filter the photos by the active year for React to re-render on every state update (year change).

```js
const filteredPhotos = photos.filter((photo) => photo.date === filterDate)
```

Now pass this variable to the `ImageGrid` component

```
<ImageGrid photos={filteredPhotos}></ImageGrid>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-http-v5dhd?file=/src/ImageGallery.js)

---

This is unrelated to your question but I would recommend renaming `filterDate` to `filterYear` for clarity.